# Comparing Same values of table

Tags: sql

Can anyone please explain me the code below:

```
select e1.Name as 'Employee', e1.Salary
from Employee e1
where 3 >
(
    select count(distinct e2.Salary)
    from Employee e2
    where e2.Salary > e1.Salary
)
;
```

especially the line

```
  where e2.Salary > e1.Salary
```

What does comparing the same values(i.e Salary) from the same tables(e1,e2 though same but different alias) imply and why we do it?
If anyone has good  reference material regarding this, please post it here.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS, only tag the one you are actually using.

Comment: Side note, don't use literal strings for aliases; using single quotes (`'`) to delimit identify objects is only allowed in that syntax. Using it for aliasing can be confusing, as other syntax, like `WHERE 'My Column' = 1` or `ORDER BY 'My Column'` do not operate the same way, and `'My Column'` would be treated as a literal string in both cases; not a column named/aliased as `'My Column'`. This can lead to unexpected or undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a *correlated subquery*.  You are starting with a query like this:

```
select e1.Name as Employee, e1.Salary
from Employee e1;
```

This query returns all rows from `Employee`.  You can think of the database engine as looping through each row, which for the purposes of this query is actually called `e1`.

Then for each row, it conceptually runs the subquery:

```
(select count(distinct e2.Salary)
 from Employee e2
 where e2.Salary > e1.Salary
-------^ correlation clause
)
```

In this subquery it goes through the table again.  And for each row in the table, it compares the salaries.  It then does the `count(distinct)` and the rest of the comparisons to see if the `e1` row should stay in the result set or be filtered out.

Note:  This is all conceptual.  A correlated subquery does not require that there actually be two loops that are running.  Queries just describe the *result set*.  The optimizer chooses the best method for generated the correct results.

Comment: Can you suggest any links for such type of questions Or any other reading materials? It's little bit trick when comparing same table and getting a solution out of it.

Comment: @user2755407 . . . Having written a book (in its Second Edition) on using SQL for data analysis, I am quite biased toward my books.

Comment: haha..thanks..Pleasure to meet you Mr Gordon Linoff :)